# Turning on the 404 page on localhost

Tags: templates, 404-error, localhost

I'm using my localhost (XAMPP client) to test my WordPress website and everything works fine, till it comes to verifying how does my `404.php` template looks like. I can't preview any changes, because it never loads the actual site, just the localhost warning about non-existing content. I believe I have to change something in Apache's settings, but I can't really figure out, what.

Will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Well, in case anyone will ever need this... You might as well just use localhost/yoursite/?page_id=99999 . At least I found it working for me.

Comment: If you're simulating a virtual host (e.g. local.dev) you'd get the `404.php`. Maybe you should take a look a my Gist on virtual hosts: https://gist.github.com/hofmannsven/6526824